# Texture Paint gives off a checkboard color

Tags: texturing, color

I am trying to paint my texture and when I try to paint it gives off a checkboard color no matter what color it is. Is there a button that needs to be toggled off that im not seeing ?

Blender File Below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an image texture set as your brush - remove that, and then you will be able to paint.[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be something dumb like that hahaha

Comment: I knew what it was because I have done it before :D